# asp.net and c# with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("my_label_name"))
     .Attributes.Add("onclick","javascript:myJavaScriptFunction('"
                               + data1_from_db + "','"+data2_from_db+"')");
```

I wrote this code (this code is in my `default.aspx.cs`) and this worked successfully at *localhost* but at server didn't work. And gives no error about working. Just it doesn't work. If any incomprehensible places have, please, ask me.

Comment: Why would you ever need to specify javascript: in an onclick? The only option IS JAVASCRIPT.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Define "doesn't work."  Does it emit any JavaScript to the page?  Can you add some logging around the code so that you can see what's going on on the server, or remote-debug it to step through?

Comment: `javascript:` is unnecessary ...

Comment: Give more details. Post your JavaScript function and any error message.

Comment: Maybe data1_from_db and data2_from_db are inputs that contain characters which will break the javascript code

Comment: Try to enable your browser debug console and then re-run your page.  I think there is a JavaScript problem.

Comment: this code is for my linkbutton. if linkbutton is clicked this code runs and sends data_from_db's to the javascript function as parameters. in fact i want to write an event to the linkbutton in default.aspx and trigger the javascript function. and i have to send some data_db as parameter to this function. i dont know how do this.

Comment: @AdrianIftode this code run at my localhost successfully

Comment: Where is 'javascript:myJavaScriptFunction' defined? Can you confirm the .js file it's defined in (if any) is being loaded on the server?

Comment: yeah i loaded my javascript file to the server. and i enter the tag of this script file to my default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the call to the `myJavaScriptFunction` is probably failing. Your javascript file (.js) is probably either not included or not marked as `content` within the project and would not get copied as part of the server installation.

**EDIT:** Based on your comments to my answer, it seems that your javascript (.js file) is being included and called on your server. If that is true, it is possible to debug your javascript by either using ([IE Developer Tools - F12](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) or something like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) in FireFox to see what's happening within your javascript.

Comment: i thought about your solution. but i control it by another function ("alert();") and it run.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you saying that you put an `alert` inside of your `myJavaScriptFunction` and it displays correctly when run on the server?

Comment: So, if you're saying that the function is being called correctly, then you need to add your javascript to the question so we can see if there's maybe something within the function that's not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Is that part of code an update you made to your page that was already on the server? If so, just try clearing your cache. This just might work.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that there is data on the server side.  Say for example you are pulling info from localhost and everything is fine because that data does exist in the database on your local machine, however this data may not exist on the server's database.  Double check to make sure it does and that the table name / info matches and so does the connection string.